# Getting another aggregate value from a previously aggregated value

Tags: sql, postgresql, count, aggregate-functions, aggregate

If I have an Sql query like this :

```
select 
    ..., count(t2.value) as t2_count, count(t3.value) as t3_count
from 
    table t1
left join
    table2 t2
on
    t2.id = t1.id
left join
    table3 t3
on
    t3.id = t1.id
group by
    t1.id
order by
    t1.id;
```

This will result to a table like this :

```
|... | ... | t2_count | t3_count
------------------------------------
|... | ... | 3        | 4
|... | ... | 3        | 3
```

Right now I'm just using the count aggregate in Postgres, what I want to achieve is another aggregate column using the values of t2_count and t3_count as parameters. Specifically to check If they match like :

```
|... | ... | t2_count | t3_count | (aggregate, match?)
-----------------------------------------
|... | ... | 3        | 4        | false
|... | ... | 3        | 3        | true
```

How do I do this in Postgresql ? Thank you!

Comment: Wrap select ... t2_count, t3_count , t2_count = t3_count from (original query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need another aggregate to achieve what you want. You can use a simple `CASE` expression:

```
select 
    ..., count(t2.value) as t2_count, 
         count(t3.value) as t3_count,
    CASE WHEN count(t2.value) =  count(t3.value) THEN 'True'
         ELSE 'false'
    END AS "Match"
from 
    table t1
left join
    table2 t2
on
    t2.id = t1.id
left join
    table3 t3
on
    t3.id = t1.id
group by
    t1.id
order by
    t1.id;
```

Comment: That was fast, didn't thought this was so simple.. by the way the 'Match' is a reserved keyword (just tested it today) so I had to change the name. But thanks! will accept this.

Comment: There is no need for a `case`. `count(t2.value) =  count(t3.value)` will return a boolean which can be cast to text if necessary: `select true::text`